# Hide a forum title at forumotion platform (phpBB3) with javascript/css

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to hide a forum title at the home page of forumotion platform. I tried this code in javascript

```
document.getElementsByClassName("hierarchy")[24].style.visibility='hidden';
```

which works well in [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) but is does not seem to work when I implement it at home page of my forum through javascript code management, the title is still there :/

[image: http://oi59.tinypic.com/1gsz2u.jpg]

I would like to hide the text "Games Section", which is the forum title. It is an href that leads to a subforum. I want to hide this so the members would have to click at the picture of the forum, which will lead them to another page I have chosen (I can alter this from forum description at admin panel, bit I cannot change href of "Games Section" forum title because I cannot change the template of phpBB3 or change the home page html).

I think this is the code for this part of the forum

```
<ul class="topiclist forums">
  <li class="row"><dl class="icon" style="background:url(http://www.esecuredata.com/forums/styles/IDLaunch_Fresh/imageset/forum_unread.gif) no-repeat scroll 10px 50%;"><dd class="dterm">
  <div style="display: block; margin : 0 0px 0 42px;">
    <h3 class="hierarchy">
      <a href="/f1-forum" class="forumtitle">Σειρές</a>
    </h3>
    <br />
    <a href="http://retrocartoonsgreek.omgforum.net/h10-page"><img style="width: 122px; height: 43px;" border="0" alt="Seires" src="http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/7186/47770160.png" /></a>
    <p>
      <span style="font-family: 'Comic Sans MS'; font-size: 13px;">
        <span style="LINE-HEIGHT: normal; FONT-SIZE: 13px">
          <span style="font-family: 'Comic Sans Ms';">Σε αυτή την κατηγορία θα ανεβαίνουν σειρές!!
          </span>
        </span>
      </span>
    </p>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding script at the bottom of `body`:

```
<body>
.
.
.
<script>
document.getElementsByClassName("hierarchy")[24].style.visibility='hidden';
</script>
</body>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7VTVt/)**

---

If you can use jQuery try:

```
 $(window).load(function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName("hierarchy")[24].style.visibility='hidden';
 });
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7VTVt/1/)**

Comment: Unfortunately I have no access to the forum's home page html code and I can only add javascript or css code :)

Comment: It works like a charm, thanks Zword! I wonder though why javascript did not work